# CKEDITOR 4 - Text extending beyond right margin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor

I'm having this problem only on Google Chrome (any version). This piece of text is not breaking the line. Firefox and others are OK.
I followed a tip which was to adjust the margins via CSS, but without success

**Chrome**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5tq.png)

**Firefox**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCKpD.png)